# How do I align my (right) header page number with the right-side margin of the body text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm a newbie to LaTeX; using Overleaf to write a journal article. I used fancyhdr to create a running header with the page number on the top right, but the number is not aligned with where the body of my text ends (i.e. the right-hand margin of the body); the number appears before where the body's margin is. Is there a way to move the page number more to the right? I tried to search for answers on here and elsewhere online but haven't been able to find anything yet.

Here's a minimal working example without the title page:

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4paper, oneside]{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx, setspace} \pagestyle{fancy}
```

Creating header:

```
\fancyhf{} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \lhead{RUNNING HEAD} \rhead{\thepage}
```

Setting the margin:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

Sample paragraph:

```
\begin{document} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed consequat, elit et tincidunt ullamcorper, felis quam auctor lectus, id eleifend velit mi eget arcu. Quisque aliquam, mi eu maximus eleifend, metus lorem pharetra eros, vel porttitor velit ante ut leo. Vestibulum eget venenatis urna. Cras leo justo, ornare maximus scelerisque eu, bibendum id lorem.
\end{document}
```

I've attached an image of what the header currently looks like as well. [image]

Comment: Could you post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that we can help you better?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment; I edited it, is that kind of what you're looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately not a MWE, as a typical MWE would be starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` The idea is that we can run e.g. pdflatex / xelatex on it.

Comment: Maybe simply trying `\rhead{\raggedleft\thepage}`?

Comment: Hmm that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Change the page margin (using `geometry`) before you use `fancyhdr`.

Comment: esdd oh yeah of course! Changing the marging before using fancyhdr worked, thank you!